# Chow's Lemma proof in Milne's Book: Cartesian diagram

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

I'm reading the proof of the following statement in Milne's book "Algebraic geometry".

> **Chow's Lemma:** Let $V$ be a complete irreducible variety. There exists a projective variety $V'$ and a surjective map $f:V'\to V$ such that for some dense open subset $U\subseteq V$ the map $f:f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is an isomorphism.

At page 166 of [the book](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf) the author says (I use an image because MSE doesn't support tikzcd diagrams)

[image]

First of all I don't understand what is the upper map of the first diagram. Secondly, I'm really not familiar with "cartesian diagrams" and "pullbacks/pushouts". Could you explicitate this reasoning a bit more?

(The author is trying to prove that $f^{-1}(U_i)\subseteq q^{-1}(V_i)$.)

Comment: I think it would take more context to answer the first question. For the second one, “Cartesian diagram” means that your diagram is two maps $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow D$ and $A \rightarrow C \rightarrow D$ such that these maps induce an isomorphism $A \cong B \times_D C$.

Comment: You can consult the book in the link to have more context (page 166).

Comment: Saying "consult the book in the link to have more context" is a bad attitude - you're actively antagonizing people who could answer your question, and you're not following site guidelines that questions should be self-contained. -1

Comment: @HankScorpio I don't see how referring to a page of a book is bad attitude... The author of the book certainly explained the context better than I could ever do. I can't see the point of basically copying a whole page of a book when it's a respected and very well known source.

Comment: Aphelli has suggested an improvement to make it more likely people will answer your question and you have said "nah". The reason you should add context from the book to this post is because [posts should be self-contained](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/how-self-contained-should-questions-be) - this is a basic rule here at MSE. It also makes it easier for others to answer your question. If you don't want to make it easier for people to answer your question, I think that's a bad attitude.

Comment: @HankScorpio I know this isn't a justification, but lately I've been dealing with some personal problems. I'm sorry for my immature behaviour: I usually make posts of higher quality than this one. I'll add as soon as possible the necessary details to make this question self-contained. It may take some time, because I have to transcribe a whole page of proof but I'll do it. I'm deeply sorry.

Comment: @Aphelli MSE doesn't allow to tag more than one person. I just wanted to tell you that I'm sorry for having been rude.

Answer (score 1):

I must confess that I have not gone through the proof that you recommended I go through, but from what I can see on screen, I can try and intuitively explain what fiber product does. In simple terms, as the name suggests, it is trying to tell us the fiber (i.e. inverse image) of a morphism. There are other uses of fiber product like base change, but since I am going to skip the technicalities, I'll ignore that too.

Let us fix a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, which we shall treat as our "primary" morphism. Then, if $i:Z\hookrightarrow Y$ is some subscheme, then the fiber product which is denoted by $X\times_Y Z$ and accompanied buy a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X\times_Y Z @> >> Z\\
@VVV @VViV \\
X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}$$
as well as some universal property, is the unique subscheme of $X$ whose image under the map $f$ is contained in $Z$, and is maximal with this property. In other words, $X\times_Y Z$ can be sort of thought as $f^{-1}(Z)$. As one would expect, if $Z$ is a closed (resp. open) subsheme of $Y$, then the fiber product is also a closed (resp. open) subscheme of $X$. In fact, if $Z$ is an open subscheme, then $X\times_Y Z$ is exactly the open subscheme $f^{-1}(Z)\subset X$.

Rather than taking an open/closed subscheme, another important case, is when we assume $Z=$Spec$(\kappa (y))$ for some $y\in Y$. Then, the fiber product gives a natural scheme structure on $f^{-1}(y)$.

Now, a diagram $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
W @> >> Z\\
@VVV @VViV \\
X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}$$
is said to be cartesian if there is an isomorphism $W\cong X\times_Y Z$ in such a way that the two commutative squares are "exactly the same".

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but I hope this gives you some tools to understand the proof.